# Есть данные нужно решить задачу

Tags: java, javac

Требуется запустить файл java. Я так понял, первый шаг это конвертация в .class файл.

Итак, исходные данные :

Файл .java

```
package Main;

public class Main {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(“Hello word”);
    }
}
```

Адрес jdk

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121
```

Адрес который выводится на cmd

```
C:\Users\вит\IdeaProjects\untitled11\src
```

Ошибка

> ”javac” не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой
>   программой или пакетным файлом.

Comment: Путь до папки, в которой лежит javac.exe, необходимо добавить в переменные окружения.

Answer (score 1):

У меня компилятор ругается на ваш код, в частности на ваши кавычки. Ниже норм код:

```
package Main;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello word");
    }
}
```

---

Переменная PATH (Windows)

---

Windows 10 и Windows 8

В строке "Поиск" выполните поиск:

> Система (Панель управления)

Нажмите на ссылку

> Дополнительные параметры системы

Нажмите

> Переменные среды

В разделе Переменные среды выберите переменную среды

> PATH

Нажмите Изменить. Если переменной PATH не существует, нажмите Создать.
В окне Изменение системной переменной (или Новая системная переменная) укажите значение переменной среды PATH(`;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\`). Нажмите ОК. Закройте остальные открытые окна, нажимая ОК.
Откройте заново окно командной строки и выполните код java.

---

Windows 7

---

На рабочем столе правой кнопкой нажмите на значок

> Компьютер

В контекстном меню выберите

> Свойства

.
Нажмите на ссылку

> Дополнительные параметры системы

Нажмите

> Переменные среды

В разделе Переменные среды выберите переменную среды

> PATH

Нажмите

> Изменить

Если переменной PATH не существует, нажмите Создать.
В окне Изменение системной переменной (или Новая системная переменная) укажите значение переменной среды PATH(`;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\`). Нажмите ОК. Закройте остальные открытые окна, нажимая ОК.
Откройте заново окно командной строки и выполните код java.

---

Компиляция java-файла: имя файла должно быть, такое же как и имя класса, т.е. Main.java. Далее после установки PATH:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в моем случае появится рядом с Main.java файлом, файл Main.class(скомпилированный)

Comment: Все делал уже по несколько раз результат один и тот же

Comment: @ВиталийVit если не уверены в правильности написания пути к файлу, попробуйте набрать в командной строке `javac` пробел а затем перенести файл из папки в командную строку(это гарантия правильности пути)

Comment: Кое как добился создания .class файла  
            “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac” Cat.java
          Но Запускать не хочет
              “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java” Cat
          Выдает ошибку  Error: Could not find or load main class Cat 
 Ошибка: не удалось найти или загрузить основной класс Cat

Comment: Кое как добился создания .class файла  
 “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac” Cat.java
 Но Запускать не хочет
  “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java” Cat
  Выдает ошибку
    Error: Could not find or load main class Cat 
   Ошибка: не удалось найти или загрузить основной класс Cat

Comment: давайте ваш код с классом `Cat`

Comment: package com.company;

public class Cat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Виталик привет с другой планеты !");
    }
    /*C:\Users\вит\IdeaProjects\untitled12\src\com\company

“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac” Cat.java

“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java” Cat

;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin    Путь указан создает файл .class

javac Main.java
java Main
*/
}

Comment: в  вопрос добавьте, так глаза сломать можно)

Comment: package com.company;

public class Cat {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Виталик привет с другой планеты !");
    }
}

Comment: C:\Users\вит\IdeaProjects\untitled12\src\com\company

“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac” Cat.java

“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java” Cat

Comment: C:\Users\вит\IdeaProjects\untitled12\src\com\company

Comment: “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac” Cat.java

Comment: “C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java” Cat

Comment: Все проходит кроме Запуска в переменной Path путь встал файл .class   создает

Comment: Точно заработало Была загвоздка только цифры и Английские буквы

Comment: А почему только Английские в чем смысл запуска

Comment: где именно цифры и английские буквы? в чем смысл запуска чего?

Comment: Кириллица в пути -- это моветон.

Answer (score 0):

Пишите полный путь к jdk:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\javac.exe" YourFile.java
```

или добавьте переменную среды.